# Trying to work out how to call a specific set of indexes when a specific state is chosen within 3 lists in a function into another function

Tags: python, list, function

Hey everyone hope all is well. I'm still learning and working on this. I know I have it set up a little wonky. But what I am trying to do is have my findState() function take the users input, check if the state they inputted is inside the state list, then print the capital and population along with that state. What I am trying to figure out is how to call the 3 lists in my stateInfo() function into my findState() function and also print the same index for population and capital as the state that was inputted.

```
   import itertools



    def menu():
        print("Welcome to my state altering program!\n"
          "[1] Display all the states in alphabetical order with all info.\n"
          "[2] Find a specific state and print all that states info.\n"
          "[3] Create a graph of the 5 most populated states.\n"
          "[4] Update a chosen states population.\n"
          "[5] Exit\n")

    def stateInfo():
    state = ["Alabama", "Idaho", "Missouri", "North Dakota", "Louisiana", "South Carolina", "New     Mexico", "Massachusetts",
            "Illinois", "Georgia", "Colorado", "North Carolina", "Connecticut", "Alaska", "Minnesota", "Nevada",
            "West Virginia", "Arkansas", "Florida", "New Hampshire", "Maryland", "Pennsylvania", "Oklahoma",
            "Mississippi", "Tennessee", "Michigan", "Vermont", "Rhode Island", "Washington", "South Dakota",
            "Kansas", "Oregon", "Kentucky", "Hawaii", "California", "Arizona", "Delaware", "Indiana",
            "Maine", "Wisconsin", "Nebraska", "Iowa", "New Jersey", "Virginia", "Wyoming", "Ohio", "Texas",
            "Utah", "New York", "Montana"]

    print("Here are the states:")
    print(str(state) + "\n")
    print("Here are the states in order:")
    state.sort()
    print(str(state) + "\n")


    capital = ["Montgomery", "Juneau", "Phoenix", "Little Rock", "Sacramento", "Denver", "Hartford", "Dover", "Tallahassee", "Atlanta",
               "Honolulu", "Boise", "Springfield", "Indianapolis", "Des Moines", "Topeka", "Frankfort", "Baton Rouge", "Augusta", "Annapolis",
               "Boston", "Lansing", "Saint Paul", "Jackson", "Jefferson City", "Helena", "Lincoln", "Carson City", "Trenton",
               "Santa Fe", "Albany", "Raleigh", "Columbus", "Oklahoma City", "Salem", "Harrisburg", "Providence", "Columbia", "Bismarck",
               "Pierre", "Nashville", "Austin", "Salt Lake City", "Nashville", "Montpelier", "Richmond", "Olympia", "Charleston", "Madison",
               "Cheyenne"]
    print("Here are all the states capitals in order of state, Ex:(Montgomery, Alabama):")
    print(str(capital) + "\n")

    population = [4918689, 727951, 7399410, 3025875, 39562858, 5826185, 3559054, 982049, 21711157, 10723715, 1411151, 1823594, 12620571,
                  6768941, 3161522, 2915269, 4474193, 4637898, 1349367, 6055558, 6902371, 9989642, 5673015, 2971278, 6153233, 1076891,
                  1943202, 3132971, 1365957, 8878355, 2100917, 19376771, 41594553, 766044, 11701859, 3973707, 4253588, 12803056, 1060435,
                  5213272, 890620, 6886717, 29363096, 3258366, 623620, 8569752, 7705917, 1780003, 5837462, 579917]

    for (a, b, c) in zip(state, capital, population):
        print("State: " + a + ", Capital: " + b + ", Population: " + str(c) + "\n")
    return state, capital, population



def findState():
    stateList = stateInfo()
    stateSearch = input("Which state would you like information for?\n")
    if stateSearch in stateList:
        print(stateSearch)
        print(stateList.index(stateSearch))
        stateInfo.capital
        print(stateInfo.capital)
        print(stateInfo.population[stateSearch])



menu()
selection = int(input("Please make a selection.\n"))
while selection != 5:
    if selection == 1:
        stateInfo()
    elif selection == 2:
        findState()
    elif selection == 3:
        print("Not done\n")
    elif selection == 4:
        print("Not done\n")

    menu()
    selection = int(input("Would you like to make another selection?\n"))
    if selection == 5:
        print("Goodbye and thank you for using my program for world domination!")
```

Here is my updated stateInfo(), I changed it into a dictionary but cant see the syntax why I cant close it right off the bat. How does this look for a dictionary

```
def stateinfo():
state = {'Alabama':{'Capital': 'Montgomery', 'Population': 4918689},    {'Idaho': {'Capital':'Boise', 'Population': 1823594}, {'Missouri':{'Capital':'Jefferson City', 'Population': 6153233}, {'North Dakota':{'Capital':'Bismarck', 'Population': 766044},
        {'Louisiana':{'Capital':'Baton Rouge', 'Population': 4637898}, {'South Carolina': {'Capital': 'Columbia', 'Population': 5213272}, {'New Mexico':{'Capital':'Santa Fe', 'Population': 2100917}, {'Massachusetts':{'Capital': 'Boston', 'Population': 6902371},
        {'Illinois':{'Capital':'Springfield', 'Population': 12620571}, {'Georgia':{'Capital':'Atlanta', 'Population': 10723715}, {'Colorado':{'Capital':'Denver', 'Population': 5826185}, {'North Carolina':{'Capital':'Raleigh', 'Population': 10594553},
        {'Connecticut':{'Capital':'Hartford', 'Population': 3559054}, {'Alaska':{'Capital':'Juneau', 'Population': 727951}, {'Minnesota':{'Capital':'Saint Paul', 'Population': 5673015}, {'Nevada':{'Capital':'Carson City', 'Population': 3132971},
        {'West Virginia':{'Capital':'Charleston', 'Population': 1780003}, {'Arkansas':{'Capital':'Little Rock', 'Population': 3025875}, {'Florida':{'Capital':'Tallahassee', 'Population': 21711157}, {'New Hampshire':{'Capital':'Concord', 'Population': 1365957},
        {'Maryland':{'Capital':'Annapolis', 'Population': 6055558}, {'Pennsylvania':{'Capital':'Harrisburg', 'Population': 12803056}, {'Oklahoma':{'Capital':'Oklahoma City', 'Population': 3973707},{'Mississippi':{'Capital':'Jackson', 'Population': 2971278},
        {'Tennessee':{'Capital':'Nashville', 'Population': 6886717}, {'Michigan':{'Capital':'Lansing', 'Population': 9989642}, {'Vermont':{'Capital':'Montpelier', 'Population': 623620}, {'Rhode Island':{'Capital':'Providence', 'Population': 1060435},
        {'Washington':{'Capital':'Olympia', 'Population': 7705917}, {'South Dakota':{'Capital':'Pierre', 'Population': 890620}, {'Kansas':{'Capital':'Topeka', 'Population': 2915269}, {'Oregon':{'Capital':'Salem', 'Population': 4253588},
        {'Kentucky':{'Capital':'Frankfort', 'Population': 4474193}, {'Hawaii':{'Capital':'Honolulu', 'Population': 1411151}, {'California':{'Sacramento', 'Population': 39562858}, {'Arizona':{'Capital':'Phoenix', 'Population': 7399410},
        {'Delaware':{'Capital':'Dover', 'Population': 982049}, {'Indiana':{'Capital':'Indianapolis', 'Population': 6768941}, {'Maine':{'Capital': 'Augusta', 'Population': 1349367}, {'Wisconsin':{'Capital':'Madison', 'Population': 5837462},
        {'Nebraska':{'Capital':'Lincoln', 'Population': 1943202}, {'Iowa':{'Capital':'Des Moines', 'Population': 3161522}, {'New Jersey':{'Capital':'Trenton', 'Population': 8878355}, {'Virginia':{'Capital': 'Richmond', 'Population': 8569752},
        {'Wyoming':{'Capital':'Cheyenne', 'Population': 579917}, {'Ohio':{'Capital':'Columbus', 'Population': 11701859}, {'Texas':{'Capital':'Austin', 'Population': 29363096}, {'Utah':{'Capital':'Salt Lake City', 'Population': 3258366},
        {'New York':{'Capital':'Albany', 'Population': 19376771}, {'Montana':{'Capital':'Helena', 'Population': 1076891}
```

Comment: Rather than trying to maintain 3 lists (your lists are not aligned btw) better to use a dictionary

Comment: Currently doing that now actually.

Comment: Answer provided

Answer (score 0):

Your `stateInfo()` function currently returns a tuple of lists.

Without rewriting things too much, can I propose the below and see if it answers your needs?

First, amend the return of your `stateInfo()` function to:

```
#return state, capital, population
return {a: (b, c) for (a, b, c) in zip(state, capital, population)}
```

and then update `findState()` to:

```
def findState():
    stateList = stateInfo()
    stateSearch = input("Which state would you like information for?\n")
    if stateSearch in stateList:
        print(f'You have searched for {stateSearch}')
        print(f'The capital of {stateSearch} is {stateList[stateSearch][0]}')
        print(f'The population of {stateSearch} is {stateList[stateSearch][1]}')
```

FYI, this is what `stateList` looks like now:[image]

Comment: Hey Gaziz, 
That worked out, I was actually reading about using lists that way but couldn't think of how to iterate it because its my first time using them that way. I don't want to take much of your time but if you mind explaining to me whats happening a little bit with that iteration, that might help me out with my last 2 menu options.

Comment: Sure thing, do you mean what's happening with return {a: (b, c) for (a, b, c) in zip(state, capital, population)}?

Comment: Yeah, its essentially checking list a, and then the same index with b, c? I was just reading about this last night briefly, first time using it this way.

Comment: It's returning a dictionary (that's what the curly brackets are signifying). Dictionaries is the Python name for key-value pairs. In this case my "key" is a state and my "value" is a tuple of that state's capital and population.

The reason I preferred this over using lists is because in this way, we can keep the state, its population and its capital all together, without having to rely on them occupying the same index in three different lists.

Also, look up list comprehensions - it's a way of defining lists (or dictionaries) in a single line as I've done above.

Hope this helps!

Comment: I've edited the original answer to show what stateList now looks like

Comment: Awesome, that definitely helps. At some point I'm going to have to add another list of pictures of the state flowers. Is it as simple to add in another value. Like {a:(b, c, d) for (a, b, c, d) in zip(state, capital, population, flower)?

When I need to pull the 5 highest populations would I flip it to find the max, like {c: (a)} for (a,c) in zip(state, population). To have the state and population to form a graph?

Also for some reason my IDE is still printing across the screen, I may have a misstype somewhere.

Answer (score 0):

Maintaining and aligning 3 lists is not ideal. Better to have a dictionary (JSON on disk). Here's a fragment of a JSON file with a suggestion for an appropriate structure:

```
{
  "Alabama": {
    "capital": "Montgomery",
    "population": 4874747
  },
  "Alaska": {
    "capital": "Juneau",
    "population": 739795
  },
  "Arizona": {
    "capital": "Phoenix",
    "population": 7016270
  }, # and so on
```

Then you have a simpler structure to the program. Something like this:

```
import json

with open('USA.json') as j:
    USA = json.load(j)

while True:
    print("\nWelcome to my state altering program!\n"
          "[1] Display all the states in alphabetical order with all info.\n"
          "[2] Find a specific state and print all that states info.\n"
          "[3] Create a graph of the 5 most populated states.\n"
          "[4] Update a chosen states population.\n"
          "[5] Exit\n")
    match input('Select a function: '):
        case '1':
            for state in sorted(USA):
                capital = USA[state]['capital']
                population = USA[state]['population']
                print(f'{state}, {capital}, {population:,}')
        case '2':
            state = input('Select state name: ')
            data = USA.get(state)
            population = data['population'] if data else -1
            capital = data['capital'] if data else 'n/a'
            print(f'{state}, {capital}, {population:,}')
        case '3' | '4':
            pass  # not yet implemented
        case '5':
            break
        case _:
            print('Invalid selection')
```

Comment: I updated my stateInfo() to be a dictionary but not sure why I cant close it.

Comment: @JakeScanlan I am unfamiliar with the concept of closing a dictionary

Comment: I fixed my dictionary, I'm trying to work out my function to find the 5 max populations now, trying to use nlargest